# Specify background-color as inline style for a row when there's a global style for <td>

Tags: css, html, mediawiki

In a MediaWiki page, I'd like to set the background color for a specific table row. The site's global stylesheet already has a style for `<td>`, so the cells do not inherit the style from `<tr>` as they do by default:

```css
td {
  background-color:Salmon;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Salmon</td></tr>
<tr style="background-color:Olive;">
<td>Olive</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Salmon</td></tr>
</table>
```

Since this is MediaWiki, [I can only set attributes on table tags](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Attributes_on_rows). Can I somehow override `:td{background-color}` style to the default `inherit` for the table with them without having to copy it into each cell?

Judging by https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax , this doesn't seem likely.

Comment: You you want every `td` to have the same background colour as the `table`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `inline`?

Comment: Is `OliveGreen` a valid color? I know `Olive`, `DarkOliveGreen`, and `OliveDrab` are.

Comment: @j08691 fixed that. No effect. I checked inheritance in FF's dev panel.

Comment: @virzen clarified.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to imply that that would fix your issue. To answer your question no, you'd need to add the inline styling to each table cell if you can't modify the HTML or add your own stylesheet/block.

Comment: @j08691 well, if that's the answer, back it with a spec reference and I'm fine. The wiki I'm working at doesn't have [Extension:CSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS) that would allow to insert stylesheets into the page.

Comment: Specifying what stylesheet rule is normally needed would be beneficial. Maybe I'll find something appropriate in the stock style classes.

Comment: The wiki is https://mightandmagic.wikia.com if you feel like searching styles for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't edit the CSS, then the answer is no - you have to add the inline style to every table cell. This is why Wikipedia has templates like [{{n/a}}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:N/a) that add the inline styles for you.

The best way of doing this is to edit the CSS yourself. If you can't do that, but you are in a position to install extensions (or persuade someone else to install them), you could try the [TemplateStyles extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) which allows you to add custom CSS to individual templates. Failing that, you could create a template like `{{n/a}}` which adds the styles to every table cell, but saves you some typing. Or you could just bite the bullet and add all the styles inline to every table cell manually.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason you are trying to do this inline (you wont be able to if you have a global - you will have to use CSS) Just give the table cell that you want a different color on a class. Since this will be more specific, it will override your global on those elements.

ie:

```
td class="othercolor"

td.othercolor{
   background-color:#some other color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [TemplateStyles extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) (which is a work in progress but very nearly done; will probably work fine if you apply all the open patches) allows attaching CSS rules to wiki pages. So you can do things like

```
table.mytable td {
   background-color: Salmon;
}
```

Comment: [As I said earlier](/questions/44005546/specify-background-color-as-inline-style-for-a-row-when-theres-a-global-style-f/44028367#comment75040675_44005546), there's also a stable [Extension:CSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS) with even fewer restrictions.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev a somewhat questionable security model though.

Comment: I don't see any difference. It's both inserting arbitrary CSS into the page. The only difference is if it's inserted directly, with a parser function, or associated with a template and inserted when that template is transcluded (I guess the authors believe this would provide better maintainability). Where's a "security model" here?

Comment: [In modern browsers, CSS isn't particularly dangerous to begin with](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/how-dangerous-is-it-to-use-css-styles-from-an-untrusted-source).

Comment: TemplateStyles restricts allowed CSS to whatever subset of CSS3 you allow. Beyond XSS attacks (which indeed only work on old browsers) CSS can be used for clickjacking attacks, sending the IP and other peronally identifiable information of users to a third-party site, and DDOS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too general for your purposes, but changing

```
td {
  background-color:salmon;
}
```

to

```
tr {
  background-color:salmon;
}
```

will display the second row only in Olive, and the other rows in Salmon.